# Where to view SQLite tables Django created?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am following the tutorials for Django 1.7.7 and I am at the part where I created the tables in the database, but I have no idea where to go to view them.

It says to open my command line client for your database and type in .schema
I opened Python and imported sqlite3 and ran .schema, but that didn't work.
I also ran sqlite3.exe and ran .schema but not seeing anything.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I am following this guide.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `python manage.py dbshell` and this will open your db client with the current database settings.

Comment: CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have sqlite3 installed on your path. Alternatively, you can use an online browser like https://sqlitebrowser.org/ . Simply drag and drop the db.sqlite3 file from the django project root folder and you should be able to see all the tables or run queries. Finally, you can set up to view the tables on admin.

Comment: If you don't have SQLite installed, this answer will be helpful.